# python isn't plotting the "tangent" function correctly

Tags: python, math, graphing

I'm trying to plot the general tangent function onto matplotlib in Python but it is coming out incorrectly.

The function I'm trying to plot is:
$$ f(x) = A tan( \frac{2\pi}{\lambda} x - \phi ) $$

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter

f = lambda x, A, lambda_, phi: A * math.sin( ((2 * math.pi) / lambda_) * x - phi)
g = lambda x, A, lambda_, phi: A * math.cos( ((2 * math.pi) / lambda_) * x - phi)
h = lambda x, A, lambda_, phi: f(x, A, lambda_, phi) / g(x, A, lambda_, phi)

def generate_graph(A, lambda_, Phi):
    plt.figure()
    x = np.arange(-.95, .95, 0.005)
    #plt.plot(x, [f(k, A, lambda_, Phi) for k in x], color='red')
    #plt.plot(x, [g(k, A, lambda_, Phi) for k in x], color='blue')
    plt.plt(x, [h(k, A, lambda_, Phi) for k in x], color='green')
    plt.show()

A = 1 #amplitude
lambda_ = 3 #wavelength
Phi = 0 #phase shift

generate_graph(A, lambda_, Phi)
```

It's supposed to look like this: 
[image: correct]

But it ends up looking like this:
[image: wrong]

Comment: As best I can see (debugging), you're correctly generating values.  I don't know whether that helps ...

Comment: Your function has asymptotes that head to both positive and negative infinity - but the grid on which you evaluated it happened to capture some extremely negative values (minimum -1374823386397210.2), but no correspondingly high positive values (maximum 95.5).  I'm pretty sure the problem is simply that matplotlib is coming up with an extremely skewed Y-axis range for the plot due to this.  If you gave it an explicit range (sorry, not familiar with the module to tell you how to do this), I think it would fix the problem.

Comment: curious how that non-linear, non-constant envelope of the truncated plot lines emerges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens due to singularities of the tangent function (i.e., having `x` values around those points). A quick fix would be to restrict the y-axis with, e.g.,

```
plt.ylim(-40, 40)
```

giving

[image]